# What are the directory locations that are writable on iOS?

Tags: ios, readonly

I was not able to find on Apple iOS SDK information regarding which directories are writable and which are not for your application.

I only assume that `NSCachesDirectory` and `NSDocumentDirectory` are writable but how about others, like `NSApplicationSupportDirectory` or `NSTemporaryDirectory`.

Where can I find a complete list of common directories with their purpose and if they are writable or not by my application?

I was able to locate possible values for `NSSearchPathDirectory` enum but they do not contain any information regarding their purpose and more important if you are able to write to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look in the "iOS Application Programming Guide" > The Application Runtime Environment > The File System > [A Few Important Application Directories](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW3).

There are several useful links on the same page to methods that will help or to further FS related documentation.

Comment: the link is no longer functional.

Comment: Updated http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH3-SW3